# Error: expected ')' before

Tags: c, linux-kernel

so i am working on recompiling Linux kernel with a really basic new system call but every time i try to compile it i get an error.

```
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy1, char *, dest, char *, src) {

 printk(KERN_ALERT "done system call strcpy...\n");

 return 1;
}
```

No matter what i do i get this error.

> cmps272/strcpy1.c:6:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘char’ token
>    SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy1, char *dest, char *src)

I tried changing everything in this but it keeps giving me this error and stopping the compilation. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide us full code please. Full file

Comment: How are you calling this function, please give an example of the arguments.

Comment: what's strcpy1, a function pointer?

Comment: @StrahinjaRodic pls check now

Comment: @ChandanSuri i am not explicitly calling it i am simply recompiling the kernel with this new system call

Comment: @WhiteSword strcpy1 is a system call that should once completed return the number of times the write was used. However i didnt finish writing it yet and i am trying to resolve this issue first.

Comment: you are writing a function definition, don't you think the parameters should contain variable names ? try writing something like, SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy1, char *x, dest, char *y, src) . But what's src and dest, again some function pointer?

Comment: The idea of the author is to implement a *new* system call. No matter how it is called - `strcpy1` or `abcdef111`. The first parameter of the macro - the name of the new call.

Comment: I think the question is okay as per SO and shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Yes, the question is definitely OK and I upvoted it in the very beginning. I don't understand why someone would downvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original code (before the edit) missed commas between argument types and argument names (needed as per `SYSCALL_DEFINE2` definition).

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE2(strcpy1, char *, dest, char *, src)
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Having fixed the issue with missing commas you still miss `#include <linux/syscalls.h>`. It's very important since it contains `SYSCALL_DEFINE2()` macro definition. Please include it.

Comment: This was how it originally was and it still didn't work

Comment: OK. You miss `#include <linux/syscalls.h>`.